# Remove Gmail's Outbox from Mail in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, email, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am using Mail app in Windows 10 to sync with my Gmail account via IMAP. When I add the account, Mail automatically creates several folders like Inbox, Sent Mail, All Mail, Drafts, Trash, as well as Outbox. Gmail does not have Outbox for some time now.

So, I get this warning about IMAP settings[image: Mail app warning about IMAP settings]

Of course, I followed the instructions and made sure all my folders are IMAP accessible. I wonder if the warning is related to the fact Outbox does not exist in Gmail.

Comment: Google Mail does not have a concept of "folders", at least not in the context of folders, Google Mail only understands labels.  Make no mistake, any "folder" within Google Mail is actually a label.  Your problem is that functionality of Mail is extremely limited.  You might have to break down and use a different product that is more compatible with Google Mail.  I am unable and unwilling to make any specific product recomendations.

Answer (score 1):

The Outbox Folder temporarily holds messages that you send until Windows Mail
delivers them, where they are held until sent.

Gmail doesn't have such a folder, since messages just enter a "sending" state,
until send is successful, and when done are to be found under "Sent mail".

So Outbox is just a functional box that denotes a "sending" state,
and does not relate to any folder on Gmail.
This is just the way Mail works, and messages are not supposed to stay long
in the Outbox.

Outbox itself cannot be removed, and doesn't need to be.

Comment: How about solving the issue with the warning continuously popping up?

Comment: You need to add your settings to the post for an opinion.